# cors issue with Serverless lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml

I used Serverless to set up an AWS Lambda API, which works fine via Postman, but which threw a CORS error when I attempted to access it from my Vuejs app.

I added the following to my serverless.yml:

```
functions:
  [app-name]:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
          cors: true
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
          cors: true
```

and now on `sls deploy` I get:

```
Y A M L Exception --------------------------------------
 
  bad indentation of a mapping entry in "/Users...-api/serverless.yml" at line 34, column 15:
                cors:
                    ^
```

I have tried other indentations and no indentation, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following structure to enable cors from the serverless for your rest APIs.

```
- HTTP:
    path: /register
    method: POST
    cors:
        origins:
            - '*'
```